# Сделать сохраненные файлы доступными для других пользователей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, debian

Debian 10, Python 3.7

У меня есть python скрипт, который сохраняет файлы с помощью `NamedTemporaryFile`:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    f.write('some text')
```

Сохранённые файлы должны раздаваться с помощью nginx для этого nginx должен иметь доступ к этим файлам. Но у него его нет :(

Я делаю `chmod` для папки с файлами, файлы в ней становятся доступны для nginx, но последующие сохранённые файлы с помощью python опять недоступны и ошибка `permissions denied`

Не делать же `chmod` после каждого сохранения. Или...

Пока что делаю `chmod` после каждого сохранения, но может быть будут варианты лучше

Comment: Вызывайте правильный `umask`, по идее в модуле sys или os должен быть. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291131/how-to-use-os-umask-in-python

Comment: `os.chmod(f.name, 0o644)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте произвольную группу пользователей
2. Включите в эту группу двух пользователей: того, от которого запускается эта программа и того, от которого запускается nginx
3. При сохранении файлов укажите права доступа для этой группы.

Более строго, в man-е это описывается так:

> Группой  владельцев  (ID  группы) нового файла назначается эффективный
> идентификатор группы процесса (согласно System V) или ID группы
> родительского каталога (согласно BSD).  В  Linux  это  зависит  от
> наличия бита режима set-group-ID на родительском каталоге: если этот
> бит установлен, то используется правило BSD; в противном  случае
> применяется  правило  System  V.

Более просто:

1. С помощью команды *chown* задаёте группу владельца этого каталога
2. С помощью команды *chmod* поднимаете бит set-group-ID

https://ru.admininfo.info/set-uid-y-gid-ficheros-y-directorios-linux

Comment: Извиняюсь за такой долгий ответ, но вы лишь продублировали способ, который я указывал в вопросе, но не хотел использовать

Comment: @Inventor -  "Пока что делаю chmod после каждого сохранения" Вот что бы этого **не** делать, я и предлагаю **создать** группу.